# Одинаковый код на Python и JavaScript работает по-разному

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

Почему одинаковый код на разных языках работает по-разному? На *Python* работает корректно, на *JS* - нет.
Я написал "аттакер" на линейно-конгруэнтный генератор, в котором используется модульная инверсия. Пример кода на *Python*, который работает корректно:

```
def crackUnknownIncrement(states, modulus, multiplier):
   increment = (states[1] - states[0] * multiplier) % modulus
   return modulus, multiplier, increment


def crackUnknownMultiplier(states, modulus):
    multiplier = (states[2] - states[1]) * modinv(states[1] - states[0], modulus) % modulus
    return crackUnknownIncrement(states, modulus, multiplier)


def egcd(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        return b, 0, 1
    else:
        g, x, y = egcd(b % a, a)
        return g, y - (b // a) * x, x


def modinv(b, n):
    g, x, _ = egcd(b, n)
    if g == 1:
        return x % n

def prediction(multiplier, increment, modulus, state):
    print((multiplier * state + increment) % modulus)


print(crackUnknownMultiplier([-750039887, 1964596828, -2125634037], 4294967296))

prediction(1664525, 1013904223, 4294967296, -2125634037)
```

А вот кусок кода на *JS*, который абсолютно такой же, но работает, почему-то неправильно:

```
function getIncrement(values, modulus, multiplier) {
  let increment = (values[1] - values[0] * multiplier) % modulus;
  return [ modulus, multiplier, increment ];
}

function getMultiplier(values, modulus) {
  let multiplier = (values[2] - values[1]) * modinv(values[1] - values[0], modulus) % modulus;
  return getIncrement(values, modulus, multiplier)
}

function egcd(a, b) {
  if (a == 0) {
    return [b, 0, 1];
  }
  else {
    let [g, x, y] = egcd(b % a, a);
    return [g, y - Math.floor(b / a) * x, x];
  }
}

function modinv(b, n) {
  let [g, x, y] = egcd(b, n);
  if (g == 1)
    return x % n;
}
```

Есть подозрение, что работает неверно модульная инверсия, но почему?

Comment: В Питоне целые числа имеют бесконечную точность (сколько угодно цифр). В самом javascript (без библиотек) пока нет такой поддержки, но [возможно будет (BigInt)](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-bigint/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас в функции `getMultiplier` в этом участке кода `(values[2] - values[1]) * modinv(values[1] - values[0], modulus)` получается число меньше чем может переварить JavaScript, вот такое `-8075061793818843000`, а в python в этом же месте получается число `-8075061793818843635`. Вот из-за этого и возникает ошибка, так как в JavaScript числа меньшие чем -9007199254740992 представляются не точно.

Для решения этой проблемы можно воспользоваться модулем [big-integer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer).

А воспроизвести ошибку можно так:

```js
// XXX BROKEN
var x = -90071992547409921231;
document.write(x);
```

Comment: мне достаточно переписать ф-ию egcd и modinv на bigInt или же все переписывать?
спасибо большое за ответ

Comment: Сейчас проблема не в egcd и не в modinv, а именно в getMultiplier. Но лучше переписать все.Так вы будете уверены, что больше неожиданных ошибок не будет.